# Codeigniter session not recognized in jquery code

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have CI(PHP) login form that locks out the user for n minutes after 3 unsuccessful login attempts with disabling the login form. to check if the lockout time is over, I set the attempt time to a session(in the model) and compare the current time with the session. the attempt time is checked in login page in some jquery code. but the session is not recognized in the jquery scripts.

CI Model (PHP)

```
if($this->lockIP($ip_address)){
    $this->session->set_userdata('lockout',time());
    return true;
}
```

CI View(Jquery)

```
var now = "<?php echo time();?>";
var attempt = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('lockout');?>";
alert(now - attempt);
```

Comment: Try this $config['sess_time_to_update'] = $config['sess_expiration'];  in config.php file

Comment: Well it seems to work, but why should I ever set these two variables alike?

Comment: I have given the explanation below, Please mark it as answer if it's helpful

Comment: Is your jQuery wrapped in `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Yes it is wrapped in $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the sess_time_to_update parameter in config.php. CI use this to update the session ID to a new one. If the change happen in an ajax call, CI sends a new cookie to tell the browser the new session ID. Unfortunatly, browsers seems to ignore this cookie and keep the old session ID.

That's why we set $config['sess_time_to_update'] = $config['sess_expiration'];

It's a kind of trick we do to make it work.